# Recursive CTE to Obtain First Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, recursion

My issue may be the structure of the table(s) that I'm working with and I'm open for any suggestions.  I have the following four tables that are set up to allow a company to have a set of Questions and each Question has multiple answers.  The flow of the questions is determined by the particular AnswerID that's selected.  So depending on how an individual answers a question, he/she can be directed to a different question based on each answer.

My current issue is that I need to be able to get the first question in the hierarchy.  I attempted to achieve this with a recursive CTE, but don't believe I've set it up properly (or even possible due to the table structure) as I receive a maximum recursion error and suppressing the maximum with option(maxrecursion 0) doesn't help as it doesn't seem to complete.  I'm assuming that this is because the portion of the CTE where it joins back on itself is returning multiple rows.  Please see below for what I currently have.

```
create table Company
(
    CompanyID int not null,
    constraint pk_Company primary key (CompanyID)
)

create table Question
(
    QuestionID int not null,
    QuestionText varchar(250) not null,
    constraint pk_Question primary key (QuestionID)
)

create table Answer
(
    AnswerID int not null,
    AnswerText varchar(250) not null,
    constraint pk_Answer primary key (AnswerID)
)

create table CompanyQuestion
(
    CompanyQuestionID int not null,
    CompanyID int not null,
    QuestionID int not null,
    constraint pk_CompanyQuestion primary key (CompanyQuestionID),
    constraint fk_CompanyQuestion_Company foreign key (CompanyID) references Company (CompanyID),
    constraint fk_CompanyQuestion_Question foreign key (QuestionID) references Question (QuestionID)
)

create table CompanyAnswer
(
    CompanyAnswerID int not null,
    CompanyQuestionID int not null,
    AnswerID int not null,
    NextQuestionID int null,
    constraint pk_CompanyAnswer primary key (CompanyAnswerID),
    constraint fk_CompanyAnswer_CompanyQuestion foreign key (CompanyQuestionID) references CompanyQuestion (CompanyQuestionID),
    constraint fk_CompanyAnswer_Answer foreign key (AnswerID) references Answer (AnswerID),
    constraint fk_CompanyAnswer_NextQuestion foreing key (NextQuestionID) references CompanyQuestion (CompanyQuestionID)
)

with cte (CompanyQuestionID, NextQuestionID, Tier)
as
(
    select a.CompanyQuestionID,
           a.NextQuestionID,
           0 as 'Tier'
    from CompanyAnswer a
    where a.NextQuestionID is null

    union all

    select a.CompanyQuestionID,
           a.NextQuestionID,
           "Tier" + 1
    from CompanyAnswer a
    join cte
        on a.NextQuestionID = cte.CompanyQuestionID
    where a.NextQuestionID is not null
)

select CompanyQuestionID,
       NextQuestionID,
       Tier
from cte
```

Comment: Just to test, change it to `where a.NextQuestionID is not null and [Tier] <= 10` Does that still throw a maxrecursion error?

Comment: It does work when I do that, but I don't believe that'll give me the answer I'm looking for will it?  Wouldn't I be looking for the highest tier to get the very first question?

Comment: Given that it works when you cut it off, are you sure you don't have cycles in your data?  i.e Q1->Q2->Q3->Q1.  If there are cycles, then you don't have a 'highest tier'

Comment: Am i missing something or did you forget to specify CompanyAnswer as a table? You are referencing it in the cte

Comment: Where is `CompanyAnswer` is coming from I don't see it in your list of tables? Did you meant it to be `QuestionAnswer`?

Comment: Just updated the question.  Sorry about that, QuestionAnswer is not CompanyAnswer.

Comment: Anon was correct, I had a circular reference in my test data.  The CTE is now working.  If anyone has any suggestions on how to better this set-up I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The where clause of the Anchor says `where a.NextQuestionID is null`, but the column is `NOT NULL` right? So this will never return rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your logic.  Just make sure your data doesn't have cycles.  If you need to detect them, read up on Tarjan's algorithm or Dijkstra's algorithm.  http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html is a good starting point for working with graphs in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change your recursion to go *DOWN* instead of *UP* just modify the `CompanyAnswer` table to include `PreviousQuestionID` instead of `NextQuestionID`

```
create table CompanyAnswer
(
CompanyAnswerID int not null,
CompanyQuestionID int not null,
AnswerID int not null,
PreviousQuestionID int null,
)
```

This will help you to always find Top Parent Questions by

```
Select * from CompanyAnswer Where PreviousQuestionID is null
```

and if you need to find children you can have your recursion that goes down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; I don't think I'd be able to completely remove the NextQuestionID as I'd need to know what the next question is based on the answer selected.  I did have the PreviousQuestionID column in the design recently, but felt that it would be hard to maintain if I updated an instance of CompanyAnswer's NextQuestionID as I'd then have to query/update other CompanyAnswers PreviousQuestionID value in order to prpoerly reflect this change.